# Rate limits and max data points per upload

Tags: api, arduino, limit, rate

noob here using Arduino Wifi (Adafruit CC3000) to send data. Or try. I have read and understood about rate limits and a limit on number of data items uploaded per connection. But I searched and cannot find what the numbers are for those limits. One per minute? I have deduced by testing that the number of data items is two, and tried to send my 6 data points in three consecutive calls of two. That crashes and burns with assorted errors, so I suspect I'm hitting the rate limit.

P.S. Two datapoints per minute work, so API key, etc is not an issue.

Can anyone tell me what these limits are?

Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: Sorry forgot to specify Xively - thought it was dedicated forum.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a developer account (free), you have a max of 25 requests per minute. This includes if you have an app on the front end pulling/sampling the data. It includes all the GET PUT and socket connections as well.

Src: http://forums.electricimp.com/discussion/2108/max-frequency-of-updates-to-xively-wo-getting-booted/p1